# Can I run HTML files directly from GitHub, instead of just viewing their source?

Tags: javascript, html, github

If I have a `.html` file in a GitHub repository, e.g. for running a a set of JavaScript tests, is there any way I can view that page directly—thus running the tests?

For example, could I somehow actually see the test results that would be produced by [the jQuery test suite](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/test/index.html), without downloading or cloning the repo to my local drive and running them there?

I know this would basically put GitHub in the static content hosting business, but then again, they just have to change their mime-type from [`text/plain`](https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery/master/test/index.html) to `text/html`.

Comment: Hmm... can a GreaseMonkey script change headers?

Comment: Can you update the accepted answer on this one? There is now a way of doing this - see @niutech's answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see an html page on github as a normal rendered html page to see preview in browser, without downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446218/how-to-see-an-html-page-on-github-as-a-normal-rendered-html-page-to-see-preview)

Answer (score 401, accepted):

You might want to use [raw.githack.com](https://raw.githack.com/). It supports GitHub, Bitbucket, Gitlab and GitHub gists.

### GitHub

#### Before:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[user]/[repository]/[branch]/[filename.ext]`

In your case `.html` extension

#### After:

**Development (throttled)**

`https://raw.githack.com/[user]/[repository]/[branch]/[filename.ext]`

**Production (CDN)**

`https://rawcdn.githack.com/[user]/[repository]/[branch]/[filename.ext]`

In your case `.html` extension

---

[raw.githack.com](https://raw.githack.com/) also supports other services:

### Bitbucket

#### Before:

`https://bitbucket.org/[user]/[repository]/raw/[branch]/[filename.ext]`

#### After:

**Development (throttled)**

`https://bb.githack.com/[user]/[repository]/raw/[branch]/[filename.ext]`

**Production (CDN)**

`https://bbcdn.githack.com/[user]/[repository]/raw/[branch]/[filename.ext]`

### GitLab

#### Before:

`https://gitlab.com/[user]/[repository]/raw/[branch]/[filename.ext]`

#### After:

**Development (throttled)**

`https://gl.githack.com/[user]/[repository]/raw/[branch]/[filename.ext]`

**Production (CDN)**

`https://glcdn.githack.com/[user]/[repository]/raw/[branch]/[filename.ext]`

### GitHub gists

#### Before:

`https://gist.githubusercontent.com/[user]/[gist]/raw/[revision]/[filename.ext]`

#### After:

**Development (throttled)**

`https://gist.githack.com/[user]/[gist]/raw/[revision]/[filename.ext]`

**Production (CDN)**

`https://gistcdn.githack.com/[user]/[gist]/raw/[revision]/[filename.ext]`

---

**Update: rawgit was discontinued**

Comment: Yeah thanks for adding this, since asking this question a long time ago I switched to this service. Let's make you the accepted answer :).

Comment: Just an FYI: This doesn't seem to work at all for private repos, for obvious reasons.

Comment: It doesn't seem to load the javascript.

Comment: rawgithub.com is a private site. And it can alter the content of a page. It is insecure.

Comment: [rawgit.com](http://www.rawgit.com) works for me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: rawgit links can be used as external links in jsfiddle

Comment: For some reason I'm not getting a text/html content type on my HTML pages so it just shows the source :(

Answer (score 208):

There is a new tool called [GitHub HTML Preview](http://htmlpreview.github.io/), which does exactly what you want. Just prepend `http://htmlpreview.github.io/?` to the URL of any HTML file, e.g. http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/2.3.2/index.html

Note: This tool is actually a github.io page and is not affiliated with github as a company.

Comment: Is this also possible on private repos?

Comment: Doesn't work with frames (Javadoc): http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://github.com/MartinThoma/prog-ws1213/blob/master/Blatt-01/javadoc/index.html :-(

Comment: It doesn't work with relative images loaded via javascript on chrome. `Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.`

Comment: @ubershmekel: Could you please provide a URL of the HTML page you were trying to load?

Comment: http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://github.com/ubershmekel/mine3js/blob/master/index.html

Comment: @ubershmekel It's because Three.js wants to download an image from another subdomain (htmlpreview.github.com and raw.github.com) and it's blocked by browsers. There is nothing I can do with it.

Comment: If you could avoid using `<base>` i.e. mirroring raw.github at htmlpreview.github then this won't be an issue. Also, this whole thing should be at github.io nowadays.

Comment: @ubershmekel I have just applied the migration to github.io. The use of `<base>` is necessary for scripts and imgs to load properly. Keep in mind, HTMLPreview is a purely client-side script and it cannot act as a proxy.

Comment: It loads relative paths properly allowing for linking to JS/CSS inside of the github repository. This is fantastic.

Comment: It doesn't seem to load the javascript.

Comment: @PyRulez Could you provide an URL?

Comment: Oh wait, never mind. They just provided code for generating javascripts. They didn't put the actual output.

Answer (score 20):

To piggyback on @niutech's answer, you can make a very simple bookmark snippet.
*Using Chrome, though it works similarly with other browsers*

1. Right click your bookmark bar
2. Click **Add File**
3. Name it something like **Github HTML**
4. For the **URL** type `javascript:top.location="http://htmlpreview.github.com/?"+document.URL`
5. When you're on a github file view page (*not raw.github.com*) click the bookmark link and you're golden.

Answer (score 7):

You can either branch gh-pages to run your code or try this extension (Chrome, Firefox):
https://github.com/ryt/githtml

If what you need are tests, you could embed your JS files into:
http://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem for my project [Ratio.js](https://github.com/LarryBattle/Ratio.js) and here's what I did.

**Problem:**
Github.com prevents files from rendering/executing when the source is viewed by setting the content type/MIME to plain text.

**Solution:**
Have a web page import the files.

**Example:**

Use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com) to create a webpage online then save it. 
Navigate to your file in Github.com and click the 'raw' button to get the direct link to the file.
From there, import the file using the appropriate tag and attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/git/qunit.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="qunit-header">QUnit example</h1>
        <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
        <div id="qunit-testrunner-toolbar"></div>
        <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
        <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
        <div id="qunit-fixture">test markup, will be hidden</div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/git/qunit.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/LarryBattle/Ratio.js/master/src/Ratio.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/LarryBattle/Ratio.js/master/tests/js/Ratio-testcases.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Live Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jKu4q/2/

*Note:* Note for jsfiddle.net you can get direct access to the result page by adding `show` to the end of the url.
Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jKu4q/2/show

Or....you could create a project page and render your HTML files from there.
You can create a project page at http://pages.github.com/.

Once created you can then access the link through `http://*accountName*.github.com/*projectName*/`
Example: http://larrybattle.github.com/Ratio.js/

Comment: Nice idea use js fiddle to let the browser load the files from github but why not using the "Add Resources" of JSFiddle?

Comment: @Filippo Great idea! I'll try that next time.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little Greasemonkey script that will add a CDN button to html pages on github

Target page will be of the form: https://cdn.rawgit.com/user/repo/master/filename.js

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        cdn.rawgit.com
// @namespace   github.com
// @include     https://github.com/*/blob/*.html
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var buttonGroup = $(".meta .actions .button-group");
var raw = buttonGroup.find("#raw-url");
var cdn = raw.clone();
cdn.attr("id", "cdn-url");
cdn.attr("href", "https://cdn.rawgit.com" + cdn.attr("href").replace("/raw/","/") );
cdn.text("CDN");
cdn.insertBefore(raw);
```

Comment: Execution of script 'cdn.rawgit.com' failed! $ is not a function

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily by **Modifying Response Headers** which can be done with Chrome and Firefox extension like [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en).

In Chrome and Firefox:

1. Install [Requestly for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en) and [Requestly for Firefox](http://requestly.in/)
2. Add the following **Headers Modification Rules**:

   [image]

   a) *Content-Type*:

   - Modify
   - Response
   - Header: `Content-Type`
   - Value: `text/html`
   - Source Url Matches: `/raw\.githubusercontent\.com/.*\.html/`

   b) *Content-Security-Policy*:

   - Modify
   - Response
   - Header: `Content-Security-Policy`
   - Value: `default-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-eval';`
   - Source Url Matches: `/raw\.githubusercontent\.com/.*\.html/`

Answer (score 3):

i wanted to edit html and js in github and have a preview. 
i wanted to do it in github to have instant commits and saves.

tried rawgithub.com but rawgithub.com was not realtime (it's cache refreshes once a minute).

so i quickly developed my own solution:

node.js solution for this: https://github.com/shimondoodkin/rawgithub

Answer (score 3):

raw.github.com/user/repository **is no longer there**

To link, href to source code in github, you have to use github link to raw source this way:

raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/master/file.extension

**EXAMPLE**

```
<html>
...
...
<head>    
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amiahmadtouseef/tutorialhtmlfive/master/petdecider/script.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Github has a static page hosting service called github pages, you can find it under settings, and then select pages, and select the branch you want to use for the page and hit save.

Answer (score 2):

This solution only for chrome browser. I am not sure about other browser.

1. Add "Modify Content-Type Options" extension in chrome browser.
2. Open "chrome-extension://jnfofbopfpaoeojgieggflbpcblhfhka/options.html" url in browser.
3. Add the rule for raw file url.
   For example:

   - URL Filter:           https:///raw/master//fileName.html
   - Original Type:        text/plain
   - Replacement Type: text/html
4. Open the file browser which you added url in rule (in step 3).

Answer (score 2):

If you have an angular or react project in github, you can use [https://stackblitz.com/](http://stackblitz.com/) to run the application online in your browser.

Enter your Github username and repository name to view the application online - stackblitz.com/github/{GITHUB_USERNAME}/{REPO_NAME}

This works even without Node_Modules uploaded to Github

Currently support projects using @angular/cli and create-react-app. Support for Ionic, Vue, and custom webpack configs are coming soon!