# How to do web hosting using github

Tags: github, repository

I have a project which is just HTML/JS/CSS. 
Here is index.html 
https://raw.github.com/nsisodiya/2x2-workspace-using-html5/master/index.html

When I try to open it, it show it as Text file. I want HTML and not text..
Every time I need to update anything in Repo, I have to copy whole repo on my server to show a running demo.

What should I do?

Comment: github is source control, not a web server.  they won't host your site.

Comment: but google code hosting allow me to do so.

Comment: Duplicate question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551446/can-i-run-html-files-directly-from-github-instead-of-just-viewing-their-source

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use github pages and here is how to do it: http://pages.github.com/

Comment: I tried, but it show something else - http://nsisodiya.github.com/2x2-workspace-using-html5/

Comment: Pull the branch gh-pages, modify as you like, commit and push.