# How can I generate JavaDoc without frames?

Tags: javadoc, frames

I currently have some [Source and Javadoc on GitHub](https://github.com/MartinThoma/prog-ws1213/tree/master/Blatt-01). As you might know, it is not possible to view the (rendered) HTML-pages on GitHub. But [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12252687/562769) exist for this problem. Just a day ago, this solution can also handle frames, but I would rather like to generate Javadoc without frames. Is this possible?

(I currently generate Javadoc with this command: `javadoc -d ../javadoc/ *`)

I currently get this result:

[image]

I would like to get the same result, but without the `frameset` (perhaps `table`s or `div`s)

Answer (score -1):

Generate the javadoc as usual and replace overwrite `index.html` with `overview-summary.html`.

Comment: I don't have an `overview-summary.html`. And this will not give me the same layout, so it is not a solution for my problem.

Comment: OK, my bad, I'm afraid I didn't understand your question then. Could you edit it and be more precise of the result you want to reach (a screenshot or a diagram would be welcome)