# Change the content-type of a file from within the browser?

Tags: html, browser, github, bitbucket

Is it possible to change the content-type from within the browser?

Use-case: bitbucket & github both allow you to view the "raw" form of documents stored in the repositories.  These are returned with `Content-type: text/plain`.  However, sometimes these are HTML documents and I'd like to view them rendered as HTML in this case.

The important point is that I can't change how the *server* returns `Content-type`.

([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551446/can-i-run-html-files-directly-from-github-instead-of-just-viewing-their-source) gives a workaround for github, but not for bitbucket)

Answer (score 1):

I tried something similar some time ago. I used JQuery to parse text as Json or html. In case of HTML I appended it to directly to the DOM.

check [parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/)

Comment: I can't use jquery since it's not loaded on the page, and I think the fact that it's https means I can't use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console  (the bookmarklet & script both fail with `[Blocked] ... ran insecure content...`)

Comment: Was able to get jquery running with  `var script = document.createElement('script');script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);`, but I don't really know enough jquery to do any better than `$('body').replaceWith($.parseHTML($("html").html()))`, which doesn't work.

Comment: My idea was using JQuery ajax calls or loading the requested page as `<iframe>` within a your own custom html page and only grab its content or links and append it to your custom page. something like `var html = $('iframe').contents().find('div#iframe_content')` to grep the content and `$('div#custompagecontent').append(html)` to add it to your page. But, https may be a problem due to the cross origon policy. For now my idea of javascript may be useless but if I find out something new I'll post it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the browser plugin, such as [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) or [Modify Headers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-headers-for-google/innpjfdalfhpcoinfnehdnbkglpmogdi?hl=en-US) for Google Chrome™" for Chrome (or similar for other browsers, just search for "modify headers" add-on).

For particular URL, you'll want to change `Content-Type` to `text/html` and possibly also change the `Content-Security-Policy` as well (try `default-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-eval';`).