# embed openstreetmap iframe in github markdown

Tags: iframe, openstreetmap, github-flavored-markdown

From the share tab on the openstreetmap page, I can export a map view as HTML e.g.:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=6.047544479370118%2C46.23053702499607%2C6.061706542968751%2C46.23821801159735&amp;layer=mapnik" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
<br/><small><a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/46.23438/6.05463">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

I would like to embed this in a README.md page on github e.g.

Searching around, the closest to embedding `iframe`s in markdown was the [git**lab** guide](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/product/technical-writing/markdown-guide/#embed-documents). Following which I tried the `<figure class="video_container">` tag, but don't see that working either on gitlab or github.

```
# how to find us?

we will be here:
<figure class="video_container">
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=6.047544479370118%2C46.23053702499607%2C6.061706542968751%2C46.23821801159735&amp;layer=mapnik" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
</figure>
```

Am I missing something, or is this something better left to real HTML and beyond what markdown can/should do?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480701/can-a-github-wiki-embed-html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Not supported in GFM

Embedding an `<iframe>` into GitHub-flavored Markdown (GFM) is **not supported**. Here's the official stance on it [from their specs](https://github.github.com/gfm/#example-630):

> **6.11 Disallowed Raw HTML (extension)**
>
> GFM enables the tagfilter extension, where **the following HTML tags will be filtered** when rendering HTML output:
>
> `<title>`
> `<textarea>`
> `<style>`
> `<xmp>`
> **`<iframe>`**
> `<noembed>`
> `<noframes>`
> `<script>`
> `<plaintext>`
>
> [...] These tags are chosen in particular as they change how HTML is interpreted in a way unique to them [...], and this is usually undesireable in the context of other rendered Markdown content.
>
> All other HTML tags are left untouched.

---

### Possible Work-around

Similar to solutions mentioned for videos in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945782/5717580), you could **embed a screenshot** of your map, and **make it a link** to the URL of your OSM map section:

[image: detail of map section of Hanoi, Vietnam]

Comment: <object> is also disabled, even though it is not listed on their website.