# Github Markdown SVG file Links not working

Tags: html, github, svg, markdown

I'm creating markdown file on a Github repo and want to embed a SVG file in the markdown in which the links from the SVG file are clickable. My SVG file is saved in the same folder in the repo.  I've tried all html tags(iframe, object, img), short path, relative path, http path to the svg. When clicked it just takes me to the place in the github repo where the file is saved therefore not embedded and links in svg are not clickable.
examples:
`<iframe src="test.svg?sanitize=true"></iframe>`
`<img src="test.svg" />`
`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg"></object>`

Comment: Are you editing the README.md file of the repo? If we go by example you can have a look at the README file for https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit -- the screenshot image on the page is referring to a PNG in the docs directory -- with the markdown `
![screenshot](docs/screenshot.png)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `<iframe>` element can be defined in the markdown file, there are limitations in this regard. However, you can make the image clickable. You must specify the full path to the image in the `src` attribute of the `<img>` element. Below I have used a clickable `<img>` element that I use in my own GitHub account.

```html
<!-- Clickable <img> element for Github README.md file -->
<a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
    <img src="https://github.com/sebetci/sebetci/blob/main/images/networks/twitter.svg" alt="Twitter" width="30px" height="30px" />
</a>
```

The clickable `<img>` element image and references in the personal README.md file on GitHub are available below:

[image]

---

###### References

- [embed openstreetmap iframe in github markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402823/embed-openstreetmap-iframe-in-github-markdown)
- [Personal README.md file](https://github.com/sebetci/sebetci/blob/main/README.md)

Comment: I tried
<a href="https://bbgithub.dev.xxx.com/name/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
    <img src="https://bbgithub.dev.xxx.com/name/test/blob/master/test.svg" alt="Twitter" width="30px" height="30px" />
</a>
just takes me to the file in the gitub reop

Comment: This will take you to the address **bbgithub.dev.xxx.com/name** assigned to the `href` attribute on the `<a>` element.

Comment: Where do you want the link to take you?

Comment: I was hoping the svg image would be embedded in the markdown, and clickable links within the image.

Comment: GitHub Markdown only has limited HTML support. Support for using standard HTML/CSS is not available in GitHub Markdown. Therefore, performing advanced operations only wastes time: [GitHub Flavored Markdown Spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/)

Comment: so anyway for this to work?

Comment: Maybe I phrased it wrong. Attempting to perform advanced operations will fail and waste time. Because GitHub Markdown has limited HTML/CSS features. For example, when you place the `<iframe>` element in the markdown file and switch to **Preview** mode, you will see that the element is already written as text and not rendered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240622/discussion-between-sercan-and-joepitz1).

Comment: I had this issue and just directly pasted the svg file's code to my website's markdown file rather than calling it with an <img> tag.

Comment: But it seems Github made it easier to upload .svg's since the OP asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/70869502/21718529