# Run Perl script directly from GitHub

Tags: perl, github

I am trying to run a Perl script directly from GitHub. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551446/can-i-run-html-files-directly-from-github-instead-of-just-viewing-their-source) seems to address my issue (indeed, it helped me run dofiles in Stata directly from GitHub). However, when I type the following in a command prompt:

"perl https://rawgit.com/EconJoe/medline2014-xmlparsers/master/desc2014_meshtreenumbers.pl"

I get The following error message: 
"Can't open perl script "https://rawgit.com/EconJoe/medline2014-xmlparsers/master/desc2014_meshtreenumbers.pl": Invalid argument"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: perl doesn't know how to execute remote scripts like that. You'll have to fetch the file to the local system, then run it.

Comment: This is an extremely dangerous practice. The perl could contain `qx{ rm -rf / };` and any number of exploits, self-installation of malware, etc, perhaps strongly obfuscated or buried a few thousand lines into an otherwise normal looking script or just through an accident, hacked account, or a test that wasn't intended to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Ashley--does this hold true if I am only using code in my own repositories? If so, is it any different from manually downloading and running code from GitHub?

Answer (score 6):

`perl` can't fetch a script from a URL. You have to do that separately.

```
curl -L https://rawgit.com/EconJoe/medline2014-xmlparsers/master/desc2014_meshtreenumbers.pl | perl
```

Comment: `cpanm` also uses this in [its documentation](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus#Installing-to-system-perl) to show how to install it.