# Can I render HTML on GitLab?

Tags: html, git, gitlab, python-sphinx

GitLab doesn't render HTML for me, but just display the source code:

[image]

Background: I used sphinx to generate the HTML and tried to show the doc at GitLab.

I looked at other projects' repositories, such as `pandas`, `sphinx`. They only have `.rts` files in the repository, and not HTML files. I guess they generate HTML for their websites but don't upload to Git.

I don't have a website and want to show doc at GitLab. Is there a way to do that? Or do I have to generate other formats (other than HTML, e.g. PDF) instead?

Comment: Could you use markdown instead?

Comment: Thanks @Dónal. Looks like there is something for markdown https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4219. I'm looking into it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, Git and products like GitLab and GitHub are different things. Git doesn't ever render anything; it's a version control system. It doesn't have a web interface.

Secondly, GitLab's core product isn't *supposed* to render anything. It's not a web host, it's a tool for hosting, sharing, and managing Git repositories. However you might want to try [GitLab Pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/):

> **GitLab Pages is a feature that allows you to publish static websites directly from a repository in GitLab.**
>
> You can use it either for personal or business websites, such as portfolios, documentation, manifestos, and business presentations. You can also attribute any license to your content.
>
> Pages is available for free for all GitLab.com users as well as for self-managed instances (GitLab Core, Starter, Premium, and Ultimate).

GitLab Pages will publish content from the `public/` directory of your repository, so you should move your files there. You will also need a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the root of your repository containing something like

```
image: alpine:latest

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo 'Nothing to do...'
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

(taken from the [sample repository](https://gitlab.com/pages/plain-html)). Add that file, then commit and push. After deployment is complete, your site should be [available at `https://youruser.gitlab.io/yourproject`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html#gitlab-pages-domain).

Note that GitHub has [a similar product](https://pages.github.com/) (that works differently).

Finally,

> I looked at other projects' repositories, such as `pandas`, `sphinx`. They only have `.rts` files in the repository, and not HTML files. I guess they generate HTML for their websites but don't upload to Git.

it's very likely that the [reStructured Text](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) files are the only source that exists, and that HTML is generated from them automatically. [Sphinx this format by default](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html). If you're interested in working from another format like Markdown or reStructured Text you may want to explore GitLab Pages' [support for static site generators](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/#gitlab-pages-with-static-site-generators-ssgs).

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

At the root of your repo, add a file called `.gitlab-ci.yml` containing the following lines:

```
pages:
 script:
 - mkdir .public
 - cp -r * .public
 - mv .public public
 artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

Your file should then be available at

```
 https://your-username.gitlab.io/project-name/filename.html
```

See this post for details:  [Gitlab: host and render HTML files](https://roneo.org/en/gitlab-render-html/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a super easy solution I found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17180148/3841768):

**Before:**
https://gitlab.com/[user]/[repository]/raw/[branch]/[filename.ext]

**After:**
*Development (throttled)*
https://gl.githack.com/[user]/[repository]/raw/[branch]/[filename.ext]

*Production (CDN)*
https://glcdn.githack.com/[user]/[repository]/raw/[branch]/[filename.ext]